# Dual Boot accident: Advice

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 and I believe I hosed my ability to boot to W7 by incorrectly selecting partition 1, labeled "system reserved" as my bootload partition when it should have been outside all my partitions to the disk. (I do not have a good working knowledge of partitioning)

When I select Windows in the boot menu, I'm taken back to the original boot menu listing Ubuntu, memcheck and Windows 7. There's no booting W7 :(

My partition table lists 2 primary partitions 1 & 2 with System Reserved on 1 and W7 on 2. Then a new Logical Partition 3 containing a Ubuntu swap in 5 and / in 6 (no 4).

To further complicate things, I messed up my Ubuntu install and I reinstalled Ubuntu back to partitions 5 & 6 with the bootloader now outside all my partitions (the default in an install).

What should I do? I'm backing up now. Thanks community! Sorry for rephrasing a question that I'm sure has been asked a million times, but I'm having trouble following some of those posts and I'm not exactly sure which applies to my specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

to solve ur problem u need to first repair the windows boot loader and after that reinstalling the grub2 u can dual boot both the os

ur 'system reserved' partition for windows is overwritten with grub delete that drive before repairing windows bootloader by doing that u can install ur windows boot loader in ur windows partition

for windows boot loader

=> u need a windows 7 repair disc or windows 7 live usb or live cd

boot from any of the above windows disc and go to repair but not to use startup repair instead repair using windows command prompt

type the following two commands in cmd exactly

Bootrec/fixmbr 'press enter'

Bootrec/fixboot 'press enter'

now reboot u can see windows boot loader again

now back to grub for grub boot loader

=> u need ubuntu live usb and use " load ubuntu without install" then install boot-repair and repair grub u can see it in this how it is done https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

if u install windows boot loader u can create a ubutnu live usb in windows using unetbootin(in case if u have a single pendrive currently)

i hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: Got W7 to show. Working on Boot-Repair

Comment: Got Grub to load. There were error in W7 boot menu (bcdedit fix) and in Grub (listed my corrupt W7 entry - fixed with a grub editor). I'm good to go. Thx again.

Comment: :) good to know u made it